# ADF Pipeline Copy data "BadRequest" error - SQL to Parquet using expression builder for Mapping

Tags: azure-data-factory, parquet

I get a very non-explanatory error running this pipeline:
{
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": null,
"target": "pipeline//runid/xxx",
"details": null,
"error": null
}

Environment: Azure Synapse Analytics (ADF v2)

Activity: Copy data

Source: SQL Server and table with approx. 95 columns - with Parquet incompatible characters like white space and ()

Sink: Datalake gen2 Parquet

Mapping: Dynamic with attached (reduced columns to fulfill body limit in post) expression to "rename" columns to Parquet compatible naming.

Any good ideas? I am giving up finding an answer on the different fora :(

Working expression with 24 columns:

```
@json('{
            "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "timestamp"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "timestamp"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Entry No_",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Entry_No_",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Item No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Item_No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Posting Date",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Posting_Date",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Item Ledger Entry Type",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Item_Ledger_Entry_Type",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Source No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Source_No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Document No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Document_No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Description",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Description",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Location Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Location_Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Inventory Posting Group",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Inventory_Posting_Group",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Source Posting Group",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Source_Posting_Group",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Item Ledger Entry No_",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Item_Ledger_Entry_No_",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Valued Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Valued_Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Item Ledger Entry Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Item_Ledger_Entry_Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Invoiced Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Invoiced_Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Cost per Unit",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Cost_per_Unit",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Sales Amount (Actual)",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Sales_Amount__Actual_",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Salespers__Purch_ Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Salespers__Purch__Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Discount Amount",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Discount_Amount",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "User ID",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "User_ID",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Source Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Source_Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Applies-to Entry",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Applies-to_Entry",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Global Dimension 1 Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Global_Dimension_1_Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Global Dimension 2 Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Global_Dimension_2_Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                }

            ]
        }')
```

Non-working expression with 25 columns:

```
@json('{
            "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "timestamp"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "timestamp"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Entry No_",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Entry_No_",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Item No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Item_No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Posting Date",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Posting_Date",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Item Ledger Entry Type",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Item_Ledger_Entry_Type",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Source No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Source_No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Document No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Document_No_",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Description",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Description",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Location Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Location_Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Inventory Posting Group",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Inventory_Posting_Group",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Source Posting Group",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Source_Posting_Group",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Item Ledger Entry No_",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Item_Ledger_Entry_No_",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Valued Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Valued_Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Item Ledger Entry Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Item_Ledger_Entry_Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Invoiced Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Invoiced_Quantity",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Cost per Unit",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Cost_per_Unit",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Sales Amount (Actual)",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Sales_Amount__Actual_",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Salespers__Purch_ Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Salespers__Purch__Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Discount Amount",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Discount_Amount",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "User ID",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "User_ID",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Source Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Source_Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Applies-to Entry",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Applies-to_Entry",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Global Dimension 1 Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Global_Dimension_1_Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Global Dimension 2 Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Global_Dimension_2_Code",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "Source Type",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "Source_Type",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                }

            ]
        }')
```

Problem-solving: tried to reduce amount of columns and adding few at the time to find the column triggering the error.

Conclusion: few columns works fine, at column 25 it fails, but nothing wrong with json-object, tried to move number 25 to 24 and run 24 with success and move earlier to 25 - it keeps failing when there are 25 or more columns. But I can't find any information if there are limits in the expression builder or other in terms of json-doc and "manual" mapping.

Info: the pipeline works fine if sink is csv and schema is imported.

Comment: Are you storing this in a variable and giving as a dynamic content in mapping?

Comment: Hi Aswin! 

No, not in a variable, for now and for dev-test purpose I am providing the full expression manually in the expression builder - could this be causing the error, limits in the expression builder interface?

Comment: @Aswin! I just did a test using a variable instead, with great success. I guess there must be a limit in input using the expression builder then. Problem solved! Thank you so much for the lead!!!

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your first question, since the error message is pretty much empty, its hard to say the root cause, however I think it might be ADLS related.

In any case, you should create a support ticket with ADF, and they can see the backend logs to be able to give you a resolution.

ADLS Gen2 Badrequest with InvalidAccessControlList is a known issue, but your error message is empty.

Comment: Hi Mert,

Thanks, and what a quick response time!!

I'll give it a bit of time to see if other community members have some experience in this area, if not, then I'll pursue your suggestion on support ticket to MS ADF - even though my experience with support tickets is of very mixed feelings :(

Comment: Just curious, do you get the same error when you use blob storage instead of ADLS? Have you tried that?

Comment: Hey again, yes, same error with blob.

Comment: Are there any characters in the 25. column that might be problematic? Sometimes some characters (like this: @) create problems in the orchestration layer. Can you substitute another column with sample data instead of that 25. column and see if it works? for example  with minimal data and no special characters. I dont think the problem is with the count of columns, but something in the 25. column.

Comment: Also, If you have git enabled, this might happen because new added code is not synced from git to ADF. 

create a PR for the new added code and merge to the master branch in git, then sync to ADF, see if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your persistency!

Maybe it wasn't clear in my original post, but yes, I have also tried replacing column 25 with a known-to-work column before - I too was convinved that it HAD TO be the content of that column which triggered the error, but no, I have tried replacing, as soon as it is "only" 24 columns it runs through with success.

GIT, good suggestion, I tried to do a full publish and merge with master branch, still same error - would be disappointing also if MS didn't allow debugging before publish though ;)

Comment: When you mention special characters in orchestration layer, what do you mean? I have regexed all non-compliant Parquet characters in the translation layer, but yes, I do obviously use @ for expression builder functions.

Comment: Let me add to the string an example with 24 columns that works, and another with 25 which doesn't.

Comment: Added a working expression with 24 columns and a non-working expression with 25 columns in the post - they are identical expect from the last json object with column named Source Code. First expressions succeeds, second fails, and it fails "instantly" with the non-descriptive error mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing Json value directly in expression builder,

- You can use parameter or variable and define the mapping json in that variable/parameter.
- Then pass that value as a dynamic content in expression builder of mapping.

I reproduced this by creating a mapping Json for more than 25 source columns and passed as a parameter in mapping settings. When pipeline is run, it got executed successfully.
[image]